# Android add library in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-recyclerview, build.gradle

Note : My project is eclipse, migrated to android studio with gradle

I tried to use [this](https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView) library, i add the following code like they suggested in the link :

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Library-PullToRefresh')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':Library-UniversalImageLoader')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.17' //here
}
```

After that, i tried to sync the gradle. It takes almost 30 minutes and finally gave me an error :

> unable to resolve com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.17

What should i do?

This is the rest of my gradle file, its a standard one :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: mmm... It's a `Eclipse` project imported on `Android Studio`, right?

Comment: @Aspicas Yes, sorry i forgot to mention it

Comment: Then... Maybe you have to import library manually, like a module, sometimes thats the problem, try to do import library like a module, some new projects or libraries are not compatible with old `Eclipse` project.

Comment: I see you've done before, If you don't know how to do, tell me and I try to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This artifact doesn't exist in jcenter.

```
com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview
```

You can check in : https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter

You can try to use the maven central instead of jcenter.

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
   compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.11
}
```

You can check the versions published [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview%22%20AND%20a%3A%22library%22).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)